# while I'sure that all connection parameters is true but laravel return Access denied for user error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I Always use `.env` file to define connection parameters to connect to mysql database.

This is connection Parameters:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=lms-api
DB_USERNAME=lms_badpey
DB_PASSWORD=*********
```

I'm sure that all values is true because I used exactly those to login to phpmyadmin on the server But When make request to my app I got this error :

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1044] Access denied for user 'lms_badpey'@'localhost' to database 'lms-api' (SQL: select * from `users` where `email` = ahmad@gmail.com and `confirm` = 1 limit 1)
```

I tried that with new Database user But all have same results.

This problem is occured only on server and I have not this problem for localhost.

I am confused and I do not know where is problem and how to solve that.

Of Course I'm using [Dingo larvel](https://github.com/dingo/api) package that I do not think it's relevant.

Comment: Restart the server and try again

Comment: Have you cleared configuration cache after editing **.env** file ?

Comment: @Sagar Gautam, yes I run both `config:clear` and `cache:clear`

Comment: @Md.Abutaleb, I do not access to top levels of server to restart.

Comment: Did you tried to change `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`? Maybe your provider is using external database addresses?

Comment: I'm currently using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost, you should try

Comment: @Tajgeer, I tried `127.0.0.1` but got this error : `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out (SQL: select * from `users` where `email` = ahmad@gmail.com and `confirm` = 1 limit 1)`

Comment: What exactly your provider is? Are you sure that `lms_badpey` have permissions to `lms-api` database with `localhost`?

Comment: I'am using that server for another web app with same parameters but this occurred for this new project.

Comment: Are you sure about .env file you are editing is the same .env used by server

Comment: @SagarGautam, yes I'm editing main `.env` file directly on the server.  I'm using `lms_badpey` user for login to `phpmyadmin` directly in `directadmin` panel.

Comment: Then, it's difficult to understand what's going wrong

Comment: Do you use free hosting service?

Comment: are you sure about database name `lms-api` ? should it be `lms_api` ?

Comment: @Mohammadb , No.